# How to clone an element and create it everytime a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy the div element and paste it next to it when a button is clicked.

I want to copy the element with the id="box" and paste it next it everytime I click on the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 18rem;" class="card" id="box">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="Cat1"></h5>
        <p class="card-text">No Products Created</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">+</a>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="addItem()">Click Me!</button>
  
<script>
    function addItem() {
          //code goes here
    }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working with your code? *"which doesn't work"* is not enough information for us to really help you debug this... Sidenote, running your code: `let input = document.createElement('div');` followed by `input.id("box");` triggers an error: *"Uncaught TypeError: input.id is not a function"* Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76750163/edit) and provide more details.

Comment: @TimLewis Oh my bad I thought it was understandable enough. I want to copy the element with the id="box" and paste it next it everytime I click on the button.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, your question is clear enough, but your attempt and what specifically is going wrong it not  If you're trying to copy (or clone) the `<div id="box">`, then why are you doing `createElement`? Also, remember that `id`s need to be unique; so if you copy this element, you'd need to update it's `id` to something that isn't `box`

Comment: @TimLewis createElement('div') creates an empty div Element right? When I assign a variable(input) to it and then I set the id of that variable to be box. I guess it means that variable now holds <div id="box">. So I should be able to paste it using appendChild. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's not how that works  When you do `createElement`, it creates a new `<div>`. `input.id('box')` does nothing, it's not a function. `input.id = 'box'` would make it `<div id="box">`, but that's still not "copying" the existing `<div id="box"`; it's a new element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. `.createElement` will create a new element and you can't use the id because id is unique and can be used once in a page. You can use class for replication.

```js
function addItem() {   

  const node = document.querySelector(".card-body");
  const clone = node.cloneNode(true);

  document.getElementById("box").appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 18rem;" class="card" id="box">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="Cat1"></h5>
        <p class="card-text">No Products Created</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">+</a>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="addItem()">Click Me!</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about it and you specified :)

Comment: No problem! This is the correct approach; target a child of `<div id="box">` and clone that, then append it to the containing element. Much better, cheers!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method to clone the element, and then use the [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method to put the cloned element anywhere.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    const cloneButton = document.getElementById("clone-button");

    function cloneElement() {
        const elementToClone = document.querySelector(".clone-me");
        const clonedElement = elementToClone.cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(clonedElement);
    }
    cloneButton.addEventListener("click", cloneElement);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="clone-me">
        <p>This is the element to clone.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<button id="clone-button">Clone Element</button>
```

Just note that the `cloneNode()` method may lead to duplicate IDs. You should handle that, citing from MDN:

> ###### Warning: `cloneNode()` may lead to duplicate element IDs in a document!
>
> If the original node has an `id` attribute, and the clone will be placed in the same document, then you should modify the clone's ID to be unique.
>
> Also, `name` attributes may need to be modified, depending on whether duplicate names are expected.